# How to Show a Interstitial Ad on click of every RecyclerView list Item

Tags: java, android

Below is my code. this code only shows interstitial ads only the first item. I want to show ads every item on my recycler view. When a user clicks on any item ads should appear.

My Adapter Code

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomHolder holder, int position) {
    
    final String htmlfile = htmlFile[position];
        
    holder.textView.setText(title[position]);
        
    MobileAds.initialize(context, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
    final InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(context);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,StudyActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("file",htmlfile);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            ((CategoryActivity)context).finish();
        }
    });

    holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()){
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            }else{
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,StudyActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("file",htmlfile);
                context.startActivity(intent);
                ((CategoryActivity)context).finish();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to load again in the onAdClosed method

```
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());//REMOVE THIS
```

You don't have to initialize for every item, move the following code to your Activity

```
MobileAds.initialize(context, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
```